# Is Set in JavaScript guaranteed to be stable?

Tags: javascript, set

Playing with Set, it appears to be stable (ie items remain in the order they are seen in):

```
> [...new Set(["foo", "bar", "foo", "foo", "baz", "bar"])]
["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

But I can't find any documentation that says it is guaranteed to be stable.

Comment: What do you mean stable?

Comment: Same definition as used in sorting. Order is preserved.  For instance, this is stable: `perl -E '@a = qw/ a b a a c b /; say for grep { not $seen{$_}++ } @a'`, but this is not: `perl -E '@a = qw/ a b a a c b /; $seen{$_}++ for @a; say for keys %seen;'
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ECMAScript® 2021 Language Specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-set-objects) says that `Set(interable)` will call `.add` for each item as the iterable returns them. The [`.add`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-set.prototype.add) method says it will append items that don't exist. So the stability of Set is dependent on the stability of the iterable used. I am out of [tuits](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/round_tuit) and am willing to take it as read that an the iterator for arrays is stable (because if it isn't everything would break), but if someone pushes the guarantee further, I'll move the accepted flag to that answer.

Answer (score 4):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) *you can iterate through the elements of a set in insertion order*.
The detailed documentation page of `Set` methods is full of "in insertion order" statements.

A test:

```js
a = new Set()
a.add(1)
a.add(2)
a.add(4)
a.add(3)
console.log([...a]) // [1,2,4,3]

a.add(2) // already present element has no effect on order
console.log([...a]) // [1,2,4,3]
```

Comment: That would be a guarantee iff there was a statement about the order it does the inserts in when you say `new Set(1,2,3,4)`. There is nothing that prevents an implementation from starting with 4 instead of 1, or randomly choosing items (one reason it might is because it is doing the inserts in parallel). I agree that it appears to be stable, but I care about a guarantee.

Comment: @Chas.Owens `new Set(1,2,3,4)` - have a try ;-)

Comment: It looks like https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-set-iterable specifies how `Set()` should be implemented and it requires it to ask for the iterable passed in for one item at a time and then calls `.add` on it.  So the stability is dependent on the stability of the iterable passed.

Comment: @Chas.Owens "... one reason it might is because it is doing the inserts in parallel". But this is about single-threaded javascript

Comment: current behavior of one implementation is not a guarantee. For instance, Informix prior to a specific version returned rows in insertion order, but was not guaranteed to do so. A later version started returning rows in random order and broke many people's code.

Comment: you are assuming that JavaScript will always be single threaded. I have burned too many times to count on behavior that isn't specified.

Comment: @Chas.Owens Ok, it depends on the definition of *guarantee*. There is a standard. There are (maaany) implementations. Strictly speaking, nothing can be guaranteed to work everywhere :-) Concerning always single-threaded. For now JS is for good reasons single threaded (I bet it is in standard, too) and will be for considerable amount of time. So for current problems this is not the issue

Comment: Guarantees are related to specs. Any implementation can choose not to follow the spec, but then they are out of spec and could be doing anything and there are no guarantees.